# Subversion wildcard access not working

Tags: svn

I am using Subversion 1.10 which claims to work with [wildcards in path authorization](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.10.html).

I have a large group of project folders (2000+) containing restricted and unrestricted sub-folders in each Trunk and Tag. My current devs have access to both, but a new group can only access the unrestricted.

Folder structure looks like this in a big folder called Projects

```
Project_Folder
- Client1
- - Tags
- - - Release1
- - - - 1_Unrestricted
- - - - 2_Restricted
- - - - 3_Restricted
- - - - 4_Unrestricted
- - + Release2
- - + Release3
- - Trunk
- - - 1_Unrestricted
- - - 2_Restricted
- - - 3_Restricted
- - - 4_Unrestricted
+ Client2
```

I was hoping that I could do authz like this

```
[repo:/Projects]
@group1=rw
@group2=rw

[repo:/Projects/**/2_Restricted]
@group2=
[repo:/Projects/**/3_Restricted]
@group2=
```

It doesn't work. Group2 has access to everything, including the restricted folders.

It only works when I fully list out the path and don't use wildcards. With thousands of paths, and new Tags created daily, I can't maintain a blacklist like that.

```
[repo:/Projects/project_folder1/Trunk/3_Restricted]
@group2=
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two new forms for rules which may contain wildcards in the path element:

```
[:glob:repos:/path]
[:glob:/path]
```

I can't see `:glob:` keys in your definitions

Comment: Oh my god. I can't believe it was that simple.